# Getting code printed as test instead of PHP result

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying my first php intomysql database but I cannot seem to get a result from the database onto the page

So the code is as follows:

```
<?php
$host="p:localhost";
$port=3306;
$socket="";
$user="MarcAdmin";
$password="#######";
$dbname="trackerapp";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$query = "select * from leads order by EntrepreneurName";


if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($field1, $field2);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //printf("%s, %s\n", $field1, $field2);
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

 ?>
```

But when run instead of it executing the query I get everything from "prepare" onwards as text on the page, not the query results.

Thanks

Comment: I´d remove your password lol

Comment: Instead of * you have to use `select col1,co12 from leads order by EntrepreneurName` in youe select query

Comment: Are you running the script through a server? PHP scripts aren't run if you access them as local files.

Comment: @Saty Tried that, doesn't seem to make a difference to the result at al unfortunately

Comment: @Barmar running via the localhost on 127.0.0.1 on IIS.  It runs the HTML fine, it just doesn't seem to execute the PHP code

Comment: @MarcL, I suppose you need to configure your IIS server to process PHP scripts as it described in PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php